# How to identify and delete duplicates in SQL defined by a substring

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a complex issue regarding de-duplication in `SQL` that I could use some advice on:

I have a table with airport codes.  However, there are duplicates in some cases where one row lists the local airport ID, while another lists the `ICAO (international) ID` , which includes a leading `K` .

I need to identify duplicates such as the following:
`KI80` and `I80`
`KX49` and `X49`

Note that there are many valid rows that start with a `K` .

Step 1: I need to identify the duplicates for the above cases.

Step 2: I need to use SQL to automatically delete all duplicates which have the leading `K` .

Step 3: I need to identify in a different table `table b` , which rows were using identifiers that I just deleted, so I can update them to the surviving ID (example: if they used `KI80` , I need to change them to `I80` in this new table")

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If foreign keys are defined for the Airport Codes in the "table b" locations, you'll need to run step 3 before running step 2. Step 2 will fail in the scenario where you try to delete the Airport Code definitions when they are still in use as foreign keys elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self join in a delete statement.  The idea is to join the table to itself, but doing the match on a "K" prefix.  If a match exists, then the "K" record is a duplicate:

```
delete t
    from table t join
         table tnotk
         on t.airportID = concat('K', tnotk.airportID) and tnotk.airportID not like 'K%'
    where t.airportID like 'K%';
```

Note:  this assumes that no non-ICAO airport ids start with a "K".